# What Happened in overflow of short vs log variables in Java

Tags: java, casting

I am new to java, and I don't understand the differences between these two:

Lets init some variables for the overflow:

```
byte myByte = 100;
short myShort = 5000 ;
int myInt = 2_000_150_000;
```

I know whenever I got variable and arithmetic I need to do a casting with (long)

```
long myLong = (long)(50_000 + 10 * (long)(myByte + myShort + myInt));
long myLong2 =(long)(50_000 + 10 * (myByte + myShort + myInt));

sysout(myLong);
sysout(myLong2);
```

OUTPUT:

```
20001601000
-1473235480
```

but why do I need to do it outside two times?

for short type, this works differently:

```
short myShortTest = (short)(50_000 + 10*(short)(myByte + myInt +myShort));
short myShortTest2 = (short)(50_000 + 10*(myByte + myInt +myShort));
sysout(myShortTest);
sysout(myShortTest2);
```

OUTPUT

```
13800
13800
```

Comment: "I need to do it outside too" - outside? Outside of what? Or did you mean inside?

Comment: I mean outside the main () the only difference between this two is the (long) between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever an overflow happens, an `int` will move to the other end of the boundary as seen in the output of the following program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483648
2147483647
```

- In the case of `test1`, because of casting to `long`, the result of the intermediate calculation [`10*(long)(myByte + myShort + myInt)`] was stored as `long` which can accommodate the result without an overflow and hence you got the correct value.
- In the case of `test2`, in lack of proper cast, the result of the intermediate calculation [`10*(myByte + myShort + myInt)`] was stored as `int` but the value overflew for  `int` and hence you got the negative value.

Answer (score 2):

Your first version reads: add up my variables, treat the result as a long, multiply by 10, add 50000 and treat that as a long.

Your second version reads: add up my variables (result is an int), multiply by 10 (which is still an int but might be overflown), add 50000 (still a possibly overflown int) and treat that as a long.

So your fist version starts to treat the sum as a long value and reserves sufficient memory while your second version does this step at the very end, working with lower memory until then.